How to change the height of bottomAppbar?
I have wrapped BottomAppBar with PreffredSize widget to set its height based on requirnment but its not giving the height which is applied by Size.fromHeight(20)
so how to solve?
bottomNavigationBar:  const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(20),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          elevation: 0,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Row(children: [
            Expanded(child: Text('Add to cart')),
            Expanded(child: Text('Buy Now'))
          ],)

        ),
      ),


I think no need to use PreferredSize Widget just wrap your BottomAppBar inside SizedBox and provide your expected height.
Refer below code.
bottomNavigationBar: const SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: BottomAppBar(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            elevation: 0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Text('Add to cart')),
                Expanded(child: Text('Buy Now'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

Result Image

Just wrap it with a SizedBox widget. Also its not mandatory that a BottomAppBar needs to be passed to that widget, it can be any widget which has a custom widget
